# Can I make these changes through additional css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to fix my header on mobile (anything under 1024px using chrome inspect. I have the image set to 'contain' so you can see the full width, however this leaves grey bars before and after, I want it to flow on directly like in the photo. If I remove the two in the highlighted yellow circle it works. Can I do this with additional css? I tried the following but can't get it to work..

Sitelink[enter link description here](https://www.acutherapymat.com/)

```
.page-header  .style {
/* min-height: 667px; */
```

}

```
@media (max-width: 991px)
.carousel .page-header {
    /* padding: 0 30px; */
}
```

[image: what I need to remove]

**Update**
When I untick

```
element.style {
    min-height: 667px;
}
```

This becomes active:

```
@media (max-width: 768px)
.home:not(.blog) .page-header {
    min-height: 0;
}
```

**update** I have this code to contain the image @ 1024px:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
.header-filter {
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML as well as the CSS for this portion. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: seem to have other issues now, my additional css to show the header image at 100% width on mobile has stopped working:@media (min-width: 480px)
.header-filter {
        min-width: 100%;
        height: 360px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat
        background-position: center
        top: 20px   
}

Comment: It looks like you have a typo...you need to wrap your media query styles in brackets `{}`... `@media (min-width: 480px) {
.header-filter {
        min-width: 100%;
        height: 360px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat
        background-position: center
        top: 20px   
} }`

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```css
min-height:initial;
```

for padding

```css
padding: initial;
```

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding.asp

Comment: doesn't seem to work, I think i'm putting it in wrong: .page-header  .style {
    min-height:initial;
}


@media (max-width: 991px)
.carousel .page-header {
    padding: initial;
}

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
@media (max-width: 768px)
.home:not(.blog) .page-header {
    min-height: 0 !important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try adding **!important** to the property you wish to override

In your case in additional css try adding

```
@media (max-width: 768px)
.home:not(.blog) .page-header {
    min-height: 0 !important;
}
```

For more info -> https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: I have to disagree with this. !important is used too casually it's more of a last resort

Answer (score -1):

Try using this CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 991px)
.carousel .page-header {
    padding: unset !important;
    min-height: unset !important;
}
```